# Is there any hook_node_pre_submit() like hook?

Tags: 6, hooks, webforms

I have a Drupal 6 site where I am using the  Webform module. There are business validations written in JavaScript, but users can bypass them by disabling JavaScript.

Is there any `hook_node_pre_submit()` kind of hook in Drupal 6 that doesn't allows users to submit the form if the validation fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a validation handler to the form as follows:

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
  if($form_id == 'my_form_id')
  {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'my_validation_handler';
  }
}
```

You need to change 'my_form_id' to the actual ID of the webform.

Then in your validation handler, you check whatever you need to check, and if it's an error, you call form_set_error on that form element:

```
function my_validation_handler($form, &$form_state)
{
  // Example, check if $form['name'] has a value
  if(!strlen($form_state['values']['name']))
  {
    form_set_error('name', t('Please enter a name'));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6.x) is also a good option to overcome this issue. You can validate by altering the webform.

for example:

```
function mymodule_form_alter($form, &$form_state,$form_id) {
  //dpm($form);
  if ($form_id == 'your_form_id') {

    //validate function call
  }
}
```